# Received an offer from one company and waiting to hear from another

Tags: interviewing, job-search

Recently I received an offer from company A. However, I am also waiting to hear back from company B, which would have higher salaries and benefits. Both places have interesting work.

Originally company B said that they expected to get back to me within 2 weeks, and for this reason, I delayed signing the final offer with company A (by making up excuses). However, company B has delayed this process for over a month now and the deadline for company A is fast approaching. When I reached out to company B, they claim that they are still interviewing other candidates with no end in sight. I told company B about the offer, to which they replied that I should postpone the offer from company A.

I'm inclined to accept the offer from company A. Is this decision wise? Thanks for all your feedback!

Comment: Company A is your only choice.

Comment: This is something you'll have to figure out for yourself. We can't tell you if you should gamble.

Comment: I was in a similar situation a few months ago. Company A gave me an offer, at company B I had had 5 interviews and reference check. B kept calling me and promising they would decide "very soon". I wasn't interested in A, just B. Then B ghosted me. I haven't heard of them for the last 3 months. If A is acceptable, accept A.

Comment: Unless you are ready to take a huge risk and end up without any contract from both of the companies, I advise you to go for A. Maybe try to convince them to give you a higher salary, and even if they don't accept, I would go for them. So yes, that is the wise and less risky decision.

Comment: Thanks for everyone's feedback. In the end, I accepted offer A but didn't not tell B about it to see what would happen. In the end, company B did not make an offer after one more month. Needless to say, I was happy that I had opted for A. Had B offered later, I would still not have accepted it, I believe.

Answer (score 3):

Company B told you to postpone the offer from Company A, yet Company B is still interviewing candidates for the position?

That's disingenuous and in bad faith.

I'd accept the offer from Company A and tell Company B that you're no longer interested.

Comment: How is it disingenuous? How is it in bad faith? They want the best candidate. They are still interviewing. It's in their interests for candidates to be available. It would be in bad faith to say an offer will be made but without them knowing that to be true. But they are not saying that.

Comment: It's like asking one girl to not get a boyfriend until you decide if you want to go out with her or not but you're dating other girls to see if you like them better first. That's disingenuous and in bad faith.

Comment: It's like telling a home seller not to accept any other buyer's offer because you might want to buy their house but you're still looking at other houses to see if you like them better. That's disingenuous and in bad faith.

Comment: None of your examples are either disingenuous or in bad faith, provided that all parties are telling the truth and not misrepresenteing the situation. I don't think you know what those expressions mean. I think there is an assumption here that Company B is somehow obliged to give career advice. They are not.

Comment: I think you are making some sort of assumption here, but I don't know what it is. Maybe you think Company B told the OP they would give them an offer?

Comment: Company B has told the OP not to accept the job offer from Company A, yet Company B has made no corresponding offer. Company A will likely choose another candidate for the job. Company B could very well offer the job to someone else. If the OP follows the direction of Company B, and if company B does not offer the job to the OP then the OP has no job offers. That's acting in bad faith.

Comment: I recommend you investigate what acting in bad faith means. I have seen no evidence that they are acting in bad faith here. They are under no legal or moral obligation to offer career advice, they simply said that if the OP wants to keep their options open, they will have to postpone a decision on Company A. The OP has an obligation to themselves to weigh up risk associated with that.